# Mirror quotes CSS3

Tags: css, transform, quotes, blockquote

I've declared quotes like

```
.quotes { quotes: "\201C""\201D"; }
```

But in fact I only use the open-quote because the end-quote is supposed to be the open-quote mirrored horizontally (for visual reasons, the end-quote of that font looks like crap).

So I got:

```
.quotes:after { content: open-quote; }
```

That worked fine so I tried to apply "transform: scale(-1, 1);" to `.quotes:after` but this doesn't work. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have a pseudo element and you want to add some specific styling to it, in your case the only thing you might need to do is:

```
display:   inline-block;
transform: scale(-2, 2);
```

The `display: inline-block` will allow you to modify it properly, and when using `scale`, mind that `1` is default value. So if you have `display: inline-block; transform: scale(-1, 1)`, you won't see anything change.

Cheers!

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: But surely this will also the double the scale of the quote? `scale(-1, 1)` as stated in the question should work for just mirroring it horizontally.

Comment: Ah sorry, totally forgot about the mirroring. My bad. ^_^